# Calculate AUC curve for responses in form cbind(Count_1, Count_0)

Tags: r, glm, cross-validation, auc

I trained a binomial model using `glm(Xtrain, ytrain, formula='cbind(Response, n - Response) ~ features', family='binomial')`, where ytrain is a response matrix with columns of counts (yes), counts (no).

The test responses I've held out are in the same form of response matrix. However, the predict() function returns probabilities -- one for each row of the training data. I now want to use the ROCR or AUC package to generate AUC curves, but my prediction and observations are in different formats. Does anyone know how to do this?

---

OK. Adding an example. Forgive it being meaningless/rank deficient/small, I only want to illustrate my case.

```
plants <- c('Cactus', 'Tree', 'Cactus', 'Tree', 'Flower', 'Tree', 'Tree')
sun <- c('Full', 'Half', 'Half', 'Full', 'Full', 'Half', 'Full')
water <- c('N', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'N')
died <- c(10, 10, 8, 2, 15, 20, 12)
didntdie <- c(2, 10, 8, 20, 10, 10, 10)
df <- data.frame(died, didntdie, plants, sun, water)
dftrain <- head(df, 5)
dftest <- tail(df, 2)
model <- glm("cbind(died, didntdie) ~ plants + sun + water", data=dftrain, family="binomial")
```

At this point, `predict(model, dftest)` returns the log-odds (giving a probability of death) for the final two sets of features in my dataframe. Now I wish to compute an AUC curve. My observations are in `dftest[c('died','didntdie')]`. My predictions are essentially probabilities. AUC, ROCR, etc expect both predictions and observations to be a list of bernoulli responses. I can't find documentation on how to use this response matrix instead. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You should provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to make it easier to help you. What is `Xtrain`? The default `glm()` function doesn't have a `eqtn=` parameter. What are you comparing the probabilities to? Exactly how do you want to calculate the ROC with this data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, you could expand the data frame to synthesize binary outcomes with counts that exploit the `weight=` argument to `glm()`.

```
obs <- died + didntdie
df <- df[rep(1:length(obs), each= 2),] # one row for died and one for didn't
df$survived <- rep(c(0L,1L), times=length(obs)) # create binary outcome for survival
df$weight <- c(rbind(died, didntdie)) # assign weights
df

#     died didntdie plants  sun water survived weight
# 1     10        2 Cactus Full     N        0     10
# 1.1   10        2 Cactus Full     N        1      2
# 2     10       10   Tree Half     Y        0     10
# 2.1   10       10   Tree Half     Y        1     10
# 3      8        8 Cactus Half     Y        0      8
# 3.1    8        8 Cactus Half     Y        1      8
# 4      2       20   Tree Full     N        0      2
# 4.1    2       20   Tree Full     N        1     20
# 5     15       10 Flower Full     Y        0     15
# 5.1   15       10 Flower Full     Y        1     10
# 6     20       10   Tree Half     N        0     20
# 6.1   20       10   Tree Half     N        1     10
# 7     12       10   Tree Full     N        0     12
# 7.1   12       10   Tree Full     N        1     10

model <- glm(survived ~ plants + sun + water, data=df, family="binomial", weights = weight)
```

If you want to do the train/test split you will need to do another expansion, this time duplicating rows on `weight`.  Otherwise your test set is not a random holdout, at least one randomized at the individual plant level, which may invalidate your results (depending on what you are trying to conclude).

Thus you would do something like

```
df <- df[rep(1:nrow(df), times = df$weight),]
model <- glm(survived ~ plants + sun + water, data=df, family="binomial") 
# note the model does not change

library(pROC)
auc(model$fitted.values, df$survived)
# Area under the curve: 0.5833
```

Note this is the in-sample AUC.  You should use a randomized holdout (or better yet, cross-validation) to estimate out-of-sample AUC.  Using the top N rows of the data.frame for the split is **not** a good idea unless the row order has already been randomized.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the example of how to expand the df. That will do it, I think. (Though, too bad ROCR doesn't have a parameter allowing you to enter other forms of data.)

Comment: @Erin in this example I showed you how to calculate it using `pROC::auc`.  `ROCR::prediction` is too slow if all you want is AUC.  ROCR is doing some other cool stuff under the hood.  You can also write your own AUC function, which is what I use when working in `data.table` (not applicable here).

Comment: cool, thanks for the extra info on pROC. Don't worry about advising my holdout choices -- I know how I'm doing that part.